# Is it possible to retrieve the original value of hashed value by offering the partial search mechanism?

Tags: java, search, hash, sha512

Info: Using SHA-512 w/Salt.

I am hashing some sensitive values to support search mechanism as decrypting the values at run-time would be time consuming.

For now, things look good. I have the hashes of the original values stored in DB that were hashed with a defined salt. Whenever user tries to search with the search parameter, the input value gets hashed with the same salt and I simply match the two hashed values. That suffices my work.

But now, I want to offer partial search. So, if I have the hash values of "Hello", "Hi", "Howdy" stored and if the users enters "H", all three values should be matched and retrieved.

Is it possible to obtain this functionality?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible due to how hash algorithms work

Comment: I don't quite understand what is that search. What user gains from searching if your database only contains hashed values? That conceptually is only ever able to answer a question of whether exact string is in your dataset, nothing else.

Comment: Maybe with rainbow tables? But they're multi-GB to store and probably not too fast. And they would give you a distance more than an exact match...

Comment: Something like this is possible with [locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), but not with cryptographic hashes like SHA-512.

Comment: The design of SHA-xxx is precisely to avoid unhashing it... so the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, that is not possible.

Let me clarify and explain: you want to know whether you can know from inserting H in the search field, if the hash is related to the hash of "Hi, Howdy, Hello", whatsoever. Right?

If that is the case, it is not possible as the characteristics of a secure hash function is, that the change of a single input, significantly changes the entirety of the resulting hash value.

This characteristic is called pre-image resistance.

More information on hashes can be found for example [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/what-are-preimage-resistance-and-collision-resistance-and-how-can-the-lack-ther#1174)